# Apache2 ist still showing the default index.html after replacing it

Tags: server, apache2

In the root folder of the Apache I replaced the `/var/www/html/index.html` by my own `index.html` file and delted the old `index.html`. After that I restarted the Apache server.

When I now call the server by `ipAdress` there is still the default `index.html`.
When I call the server by `ipAdress/index.html` I will get the new `index.html`.

How can I change the config, that the server delivers by call up via `ipAdress` the new `index.html`?

Comment: First thought: cache. Open the page and press ctrl+f5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is your web browser caching the old page? Try holding Shift and clicking the reload button.